# Cakephp, delete action with Js helper and render ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp

I'm using a Js Helper so i can be able to delete one record from my table.
To do that in my view named as 'myclients' i use a link called "Remove" so when i click it will remove one record from my table and will use ajax to update the table without refresh my page.

```
<?php echo $this->Js->link(
                    'Remove', 
                    '/Users/remove/'.$u['User']['id'].'/page:'.$this->Paginator->counter(array('format' => '%page%')), 
                    array('target' => '_self', 'update' => '#my_listview', 'escape' => false, 'confirm' => 'Are you sure?')); 
                    ?>
```

Following my controller i use the following code:

```
public function remove($id=null){

                $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('invalid user'), 'default', array ('class' => 'primary alert'));

            throw new NotFoundException(__('invalid user'));
        }

                if ($this->User->delete()) {
            $this->Paginator->settings = array(
                'limit' => 10,
                'order' => array(
                    'User.id' => 'asc'
                )
            );          
            $this->set('Users', $this->paginate('User'));
            $this->render('myclients', 'ajax');
        }
```

This seems to work fine, but just only one time,this it will remove and update my table, but when i click the second time in other record, it will remove but it wont update my table it will refresh my page and show a page blank page only with my table all css doesn't seems to load.
Notice that the confirm question does it show up only in the first time.

Thanks in advance.

You can see my view on [github](https://gist.github.com/MrZogs/6551100d1f8d1e8428a9). Notice that the code that i put on stackoverflow is translated with diferent names, but follow the same logic.

Comment: it seems that you have some kind of js problem. So the second time you don't call the delete action via ajax but just follow the link in a 'traditional' way. So the browser render the `myclient` view. Could be?

Comment: Right! It seems that cake is looking for remove view, but i want a ajax request, i dont need to create a remove view. I want to render my myclient view. Probably i have to do that by the traditional method..

Comment: try posting your myclients.ctp file

Comment: @arilia, i've updated my question. I didn't translate the code but it follows the same logic that is on this question.

Comment: I don't see in your code the rows I suggested to add in my answer below.

Comment: Yes, @arilia you are right, i tried what you said but nothing changed. :(

Comment: I tried a simplified version of your code, I could also replicate your issue and resolve it after writing the javascript buffer at the end of the page. Mind that you are recursively updating the `lista_clientes` div so you'll end in a nested set of divs with the same id. Check the html after the first delete to see that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54782/discussion-between-epascoal-and-arilia).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but let's see if I'm guessing what's happening.

1. You click on an ajax link
2. User is deleted
3. you update a table or a list of users with the new data coming from `myclients` view
4. the update table (or list) has delete links, but once updated the links stop working

If so the problem is that when you load a content via ajax cake does not put the javascript in it unless you tell it to do so.

In your `myclient.ctp` file put this code

```
if($this->layout == 'ajax')
    echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

Comment: On the 3. it will only refresh table, i mean. and yes 4 after refresh table after i delete a row, the links stop work. I tried what you said but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: that code goes at the end of the view. Please edit your question posting your view file